# A script to geo-locate ip addresses in auth.log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, log-files, geolocation

Is there a way to automatically geo-locate an ip-address on Ubuntu linux?  I'm looking to do this for errors in my auth.log.

Comment: What does "geo-locate an ip-address" mean?  Look up where it comes from?

Comment: Find an approximate physical location associated with the ip address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ubuntu PreReqs:**
`sudo apt-get install libgeoip1 libgeo-ip-perl libregexp-common-perl`

**Script By Me just For you:**

```
#Parses out ip and prints ip followed by country
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common qw /net/;
use Geo::IP;

my $gi = Geo::IP->new(GEOIP_STANDARD);

while (<>) {
    #Following matches IPv4 addresses and stores the result in $1
    #The way this is now, it will only do the first IP on each line
    if (/($RE{net}{IPv4})/g) {
        print $1 . ':' . $gi->country_code_by_addr($1);
    }
}
```

**Input Output:**

```
65.19.146.2
65.19.146.2:US
65.19.146.2
220.248.0.0:CN
```

The script justs loops over its input, so if the script is called foo.pl and is executable, you can just do something like `cat access.log | foo.pl`.  If you want more accurate detail, see [Geo::IP](http://search.cpan.org/~borisz/Geo-IP-1.38/lib/Geo/IP.pm) perl module docs (and you might need to install a different database).

Comment: You will want the grep function mostly like for multiple matches on a line: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html

Comment: Thats great. I would love to be able to get the output grouped by country, and #. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4):

It should be fairly straightforward in Perl.  Just take auth.log and get a list of IPs out of it with grep or awk, then pipe your list of IPs into a Perl script, and use [Geo::IP](http://search.cpan.org/~borisz/Geo-IP-1.38/lib/Geo/IP.pm) to get a country/city match from it.

Answer (score 1):

From [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4055/geoip-information):

```
GeoipLookUp(){ curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -s "http://www.geody.com/geoip.php?ip=$1" | grep "^IP.*$1" | html2text; }
```

Comment: Two problems : The web uses captcha and https:// is required.

Answer (score 0):

with python:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maxmind/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libmaxminddb0 libmaxminddb-dev mmdb-bin
sudo pip install geoip2

wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.tar.gz
tar xvfz GeoLite2-City.tar.gz

python -c 'import geoip2.database
reader = geoip2.database.Reader("./GeoLite2-City/GeoLite2-City.mmdb")
for line in open("/var/log/nginx/access.log').readlines():
    response = reader.city(line.split(" ")[0])
    print(dir(response))
'
```